# Need to select the last cell in a column that isn't blank to count how many cells of data in that section

Tags: vba, excel

I need a piece of code to work for me in a project. The clause that isn't working is meant to set a Range Variable where the Range is determined with the first cell being the row/col # of a matched cell and the ranges end cell being the last non blank cell in the respective column. I'm working with data that has blanks in between each section of data with different numbers of rows in each section, all sections on the same sheet separated by a blank row each, so I need something that keeps counting how many cells in each section for each matched case.
The code that's giving me an error is:

```
    countRes = Range(.Cells(checkRow, matchCol), .Cells(checkRow, matchCol).End(xlDown).Select)
    resRow = countRes.Rows.Count
```

I keep getting an error that the *object variable hasn't been set or with block variable not set*.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

I know its something to do with that first line but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: no question mark noticed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Set` a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and remove the `.Select` from the latter cell range reference. Typically, it is better to look for the last populated cell from the bottom UP rather than from the top down. If there were interim blank cells, you would stop at the blank rather than finding the true *last cell*.

It would also be a good idea to resolve the parent worksheet.

```
dim countRes as range, resRow as long
with worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~ set this properly!
    SET countRes = .Range(.Cells(checkRow, matchCol), .Cells(Rows.Count, matchCol).End(xlUP))
    resRow = countRes.Rows.Count
end with
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response but the problem is that the interim blanks exist because the worksheets is full of data from different sources with different sizes that is mismatched by their columns and I need to match and sort out the data into one big data set. I'm trying to do this by first matching the column from each data set to the correct column I need it moved to. So what I need here is something to let me count from the first row to the last non blank row in each section into a variable to use for Resizing my copy selection later. Do you think there is a simpler solution to this?